# How to dynamically create a tree view in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have 2 database tables named Categories and SubCategories and I want to create an Unordered List inside my asp.net web form like a tree view like

ul
li a href=""CategoryDynamicData/li
ul
li SubCategoryDynamicData li
..
..
..

Any algorithms for that ? I couldn't nest 2 repeaters ?

Comment: My problem is to get values from db and insert it into the treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It seems not the best way but here how I solved this...
Hope it helps others :)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (ProjectsDataContext dc = new ProjectsDataContext())
        {
            var categories = from cats in dc.Categories
                             select cats;

            sb.Append("<ul id=\"sitemap\" class=\"sitemap\">");

            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                sb.Append("<li><a href=\"ShowCategory.aspx?CategoryID="+c.CategoryID +"\">"+ c.Name+"</a>");

                var subcategories = from subs in dc.SubCategories
                                    where (subs.Category.Name == c.Name)
                                    select subs;

                sb.Append("<ul>");

                foreach (SubCategory s in subcategories)
                {
                    sb.Append("<li><a href=\"../ShowSubCategory.aspx?SubCategoryID=" + s.SubCategoryID + "\">" + s.Name + "</a></li>");
                }
                sb.Append("</ul></li>");

            }

            sb.Append("</ul>");
        }


        lala.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, why won't **[asp:TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx)** work for you?

You could use a jQuery plugin, like the [Treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/).  It works exactly as you described, by using `ul` and `li` to represent the tree branches and leaves.

Answer (score 0):

you can display Hierarchical Data with TreeView.
See following sample to bind data in treeview:
http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2009/08/display-hierarchical-data-with-treeview.html